# Number of dice games with k doubles - Solution verificaiton

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> Let $F(n,k)$ be the number of dice games with $n$ dice rolls and $k$ doubles. a roll is a double if it is identical to the previous roll. Find a recursive forumla and sufficient starting values for $n \geq 1, k \geq 0$.

My solution is $F(n, k) = F(n-1,k-1)+5F(n-1, k)$.

We seperate to 2 cases, 1. last result is a double, which gives us $F(n-1,k-1)$ options because the last result is determined. 2. last result isn't a double, which gives us $5F(n-1, k)$ options because we need $k$ doubles in the first $n-1$ rolls, and we have 5 options for the last roll (so it is not a double).

For starting terms, I found $F(0,k)_{k\neq 0}=0, F(0,0)=1, F(n,0)_{n\neq 0}=6*5^{n-1}$.

I know they work for more cases than required, but I'm not sure how to solve otherwise.

Can anyone confirm/point mistakes? I think the formula is correct but not so confident about starting values.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $F$ is $n\ge 1, k\ge 0$, so we can ignore other values. We can now just focus on the values $k$ can take in relation to $n$. Accordingly,
$$
F(n,k)= 
\begin{cases}
0  &\quad k\ge n \\
6\cdot5^{n-1} &\quad k=0 \\
F(n-1,k-1)+5F(n-1,k) &\quad 0<k<n
\end{cases}
$$